# Group sharing photos without registration?

Tags: sharing

Is there any (preferably free) site/service out there that allows photo uploads to a single album by several people without registration?

What I have in mind is

1. I create a group photo album on the given site
2. Site provides me with an upload code
3. Anyone knowing the code can upload multiple images to the album,
   without registering on the site

The key is "without registration". There are a lot of sites that offer group photo sharing, but all that I've seen require registration from uploaders. I'd like to skip that step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**FOTKI**](http://fotki.com) allow email upload, which meets your requirement.

An album is assigmed an email_code and emails can thene be sent by anyone to
 user_name+emai_code@fotki.com and will end up in the correct album. Photos are usually available in under a minute.

You obviously want to be careful who knows a given user_name, email_code combination as it can be badly abused. The page owner can change the code or disable access as required.

Any other sites which allow email access would presumably also meet your requirement.