# Are there any photo uploading services that are tailored to a shared family account?

Tags: sharing

I see on this other question ([Group sharing photos without registration](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26815/group-sharing-photos-without-registration)) that there are ways to do this without registered accounts, but I want to do the same with registered users (ala a family account).  I want my users to be able to create albums, add photos to each others' albums, all while keeping the photos private within the family, until otherwise specified.

Given that all of my photos are already in Picasa locally, I'd like something compatible with Picasa, but I'm open to other solutions as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a single account and share the single login with your family. That's the only solution I can think of that will let you edit each other's albums. Generally different users are not allowed to edit another user's albums, at least on all the services I can think of.

You might also try Google plus, you can make a circle for your family and share images with just them. Since they're both Google products, it should play well with Picasa.

Answer (score 3):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) is a pretty good way to go.  While its photo album management and display tools are barebones, it's super easy to share albums between accounts so that multiple people can play with them collaboratively.

Comment: It has the downside of taking up atual space on each user's computer (the total space of all the photos and videos), but the upside of permitting all users to edit all the albums.

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly not perfect. But it may fit certain users' needs.  I don't think anyone's made a solution yet that really covers all the bases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually working with a client right now to develop such a service. It is iOS only, at least now, and we're not ready to release yet. But try to check back here, when we are ready I'll announce it. (Unless this crosses the line into commercialism. I'll flag my own answer here to draw moderator attention.)

Comment: The [FAQ](http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) is fairly clear on this - by all means mention a product or service you're affiliated with, if it is relevant, but that affiliation must be declared up front. Of course, the [sales team](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) would even encourage you to contact them about advertising...